# Creating html buttons in code, for table. How to handle server callbacks?

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I'm currently working on a project and got stuck. I have a `Literal` control, placed in my .aspx page and I use a stringbuilder like this to populate it with data :

```
public string CreateNewEntry(String garageName, String garageType,String garageAdress, String garagePhone, String garageId)
{

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(@"<tr class=""odd"">");
    sb.Append(@"<td class=""v-middle"">");
    sb.Append(garageName);
    sb.Append(@"</td>");

    sb.Append(@"<td class=""v-middle"">");
    sb.Append(garageType);
    sb.Append(@"</td>");

    sb.Append(@"<td class=""v-middle"">");
    sb.Append(garageAdress);
    sb.Append(@"</td>");

    sb.Append(@"<td class=""v-middle"">");
    sb.Append(garagePhone);
    sb.Append(@"</td>");


    sb.Append(@"<td class="""">");
    sb.Append(@"<a href=""#"" class=""btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-success"" id=""");
    sb.Append("edit"+garageId);
    sb.Append(@""" name=""");
    sb.Append("edit"+garageId);
    sb.Append(@"""runat=""server"" OnServerClick=""processRowButtonClick""><i class=""fa fa-edit""></i></a>");

    sb.Append(@"<a href=""#"" class=""btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-danger"" id=""");
    sb.Append("delete"+garageId);
    sb.Append(@""" name=""");
    sb.Append("delete"+garageId);
    sb.Append(@"""runat=""server"" OnServerClick=""processRowButtonClick""><i class=""fa fa-ban fa-indent""></i></a></td></tr>");

    return sb.ToString();


}
```

I then run a SQL query, to gather the data and loop trough it with a foreach loop adding all table elements dynamically to the `Literal controller`.

```
public void garageViewPopulator()
{
    serviceDatabaseDataContext dbQuery = new serviceDatabaseDataContext();
    var query = (from GarageDetails in dbQuery.GarageDetails
                 select GarageDetails);

    String _constructorString = "";
    NewListEntry tableEntry = new NewListEntry();

    foreach (GarageDetail item in query)
    {
         //Creating new HTML code from the class above
        _constructorString += tableEntry.CreateNewEntry(item.garageName.ToString(), item.garageType.ToString(), item.garageAdress.ToString(), item.garagePhone.ToString(), item.garageId.ToString());
    }

    // My litteral
    garageListHolder.Text = _constructorString;
}
```

I then have a :

```
  protected void processRowButtonClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
       //Retrieve what button id was pressed, and exec action.
    }
```

In my code-behind file. I assumed this would get called when a user pressed a button in my generated table shown under.

[image: A view of the generated list from html]

Two questions, is it possible to do it this way? Will the code register the buttons as clickable when i generate them from code? Because right now, clicking them does not execute the current **processRowButtonClick** function in the code behind.

Secondly, If this is possible, how would I get the name / id of the button pressed? Does anybody have any input?

(It may be easier methods of achieving what I'm trying to do, so I'l be happy to receive information about better solutions as well).

Comment: How did you decide to display your items this way? Asp.net has built-in controls to display lists of items. Look at GridView or DataList.

Comment: You can't build server controls like that, and building a table in a string / literal is just messy. [Use a repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx) and you shouldn't have these problems.

Comment: @RickS I knew this was not the best approach. More like a test, to see if it worked. And some input as to why it wont work and / or if it was possible to make it work. Thanks for the suggestions tough. :)